# How Can I hide the label while typing in the TextInput React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on react native project  , I'm creating page with Text and TextInput , I want that the label's text disappear when I type in TextInput Field .
This is the code of the TextInput:

```
<TextInput
            label="Classification"
            keyboardType="default"
            underlineColor="#009688"
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            // editable={false}

            theme={{
              colors: {primary: '#009688'},
            }}
            style={ThirdScreenStyle.Text}></TextInput>
```

This is the style ThirdScreenStyle.Text:

```
Text: {
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
marginBottom: 5,
marginLeft: 30,
width: 300,
fontSize: 11,
padding: 3,


 },
```

I want that the label classification disappear , also I want to decrease the size of the TextInput's field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onFocus` props of TextInput to save in state. Use that state to selectively show or hide text/label
`<Text>{focused&&"Classification"}</Text>`
Where "focused" comes from state you modify from onFocus method.

Comment: I don't know actually how to initiliase focused can you give me the code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no TextInput prop called "label", i think what you are looking for is "placeholder".

```
<TextInput
            placeholder="Classification"
            keyboardType="default"
            underlineColor="#009688"
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            // editable={false}

            theme={{
              colors: {primary: '#009688'},
            }}
            style={ThirdScreenStyle.Text}/>
```

Otherwise your label should be in a seperate  component and use @Yogesh's approach with onFocus.